# Bit Map to Base64 Byte Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, image, bitmap

I am attempting to convert a decimal pixel array into a bit map, store it, then retrieve it and display as a base 64 image for the web. To create my bit map I step through the pixel array and simply set the pixles in the bit map like so.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(320, 240);
for (var i = 0; i < pixelArray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < pixelArray.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        var color = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(pixelArray[i][j]));
        bmp.SetPixel(j, i, color);
    }
}

var img  = Images.ConvertImageToByteArray(bmp);
```

I then store the image in SQL as a `varbinary(MAX)`.

When I retrieve the image I attempt to convert it to a base 64 string to display on a website using the following:

```
var imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
var img= string.Format("data:image/bmp;base64,{0}", imageString);
return img;
```

But when I attempt to display the image, it is just blank. I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT:** Here is how I display it on the page

```
<img alt="Face Capture" height="240" width="320" src="@Model.ImageAsBase64" />
```

Where `Model.ImageAsBase64` is the returned `img`.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, so my guess is that `img` needs to be served as raw HTML instead of encoded. Show the code where you display the `img` variable on the page.

Comment: As an FYI, Bitmap.SetPixel is a comparatively slow way to modify a Bitmap's contents if you're setting many pixels.  Take a look at LockBits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Comment: @DavidHaney Edit to add the HTML

Comment: Try this instead: `<img alt="Face Capture" height="240" width="320" src="@Html.Raw(Model.ImageAsBase64)" />`

Comment: Oh.  I just noticed that you're using type "image/bmp".  I would be surprised if browsers other than IE support that, but I guess I don't know for sure.  Have you tried using PNG or JPEG?

Comment: @adv12 It has worked for other images in the past in Chrome.

Comment: Another thing to try is to debug and grab the base 64 string and test it here to see that it's valid: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode